# ROR - ActiveAdmin how to break lines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've been using ActiveAdmin to create new posts for my news app, the problem is that even though I'm using the type "text' for my body property I don't know how to break lines when writing a new post.

That's my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :title, :body, :description, :remote_image_thumb_url, :remote_image_banner_url, :category_id

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Post Details", :multipart => true do
      f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name
      f.input :title
      f.input :body
      f.input :description
      f.input :remote_image_thumb_url
      f.input :remote_image_banner_url
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

I've been googling for a while  but didn't fidn any solutions yet. Any ideas?

Comment: You replace newlines with HTML `<br>` tags.

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried that @DaveNewton

Answer (score 3):

Rails saves the new lines when you hit the carriage return. However to render it is a different thing because it is naturally escaped.

You have a few options:

- Use the [default simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M002285) in rails.
- Use a markdown renderer like [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) to do that + alot more functionality.